# PHP jQuery ajax request is not responding

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This jQuery ajax request is not working. The form submit just reloads the page, there are no alerts, nothing. Where am I going wrong?

```
$("#newfolder").submit(function() {

    alert("1")

    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",       
        url     : "<?php echo $cfg->wwwroot ?>/pages/media/async/newfolder.php",
        data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
            //$.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Is this running inside a `document.ready` handler, if the accept answer checkmark not big enough to be seen?

Answer (score 4):

This can have several causes.

- Ensure that you've included [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) as one of first `<script>`s in HTML `<head>`.

  ```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  ```
- Ensure that you're calling this function when the document is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) loading.

  ```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          // Here.
      });
  </script>
  ```
- Ensure that the element with `id="newFolder"` is present in HTML DOM tree and supports the `submit` event.

  ```
  <form id="newFolder">
  ```

Comment: thats it... i was missing the '$(document).ready(function() {
' - as i thought i only needed that for onload stuff....thanks!

Comment: Without it, the script in `<head>` would be executed *before* the document is ready loading and thus you may risk that the element with `id="newFolder"` isn't reachable yet at that point.